# C++ class member seen as "not defined"

Tags: c++, class, pointers, member

I have the following class:

```
class clsTree;
{
private:
    vector<clsNode*>m_content;
    m_RootNode *clsNode;
    m_LastNode *clsNode;
public:
    vector<clsNode*>Content;
    wstring interpret(wstring uWord);
};
```

The compiler does not like my member declaration of clsNode at all.

The first error I get is "Member clsTree::clsNode is not a type name.".

I don't see where I went wrong.
Can somebody help, please?

Comment: Aww, my friend, at least learn the syntax first... C++ ain't no Pascal...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not showing the definition of `clsNode`, neither whether you have a forward declaration for it, but I'm pretty sure this:

```
m_RootNode *clsNode;
m_LastNode *clsNode;
```

Should be rewritten this way:

```
clsNode* m_RootNode;
clsNode* m_LastNode;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I just didn't see this :-)